# incompatible types pwidechar and string ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, shellexecute

I try to compress files using `winrar` command line,
But when I add a variable in the command line I get these error 
**Incompatible types 'PWideChar' and 'string'** !

I convert the sdate variable to WideChar but it's not work !!

**How I can fix it !**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
mydate : TDateTime;
sdate : string;
begin
mydate:= Now-7;
sdate := FormatDateTime('YYYY/mm/dd',mydate);
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRar.exe'),
    'a -r -ta'+ PChar(sdate) +' D:\xlsFiles.rar D:\*.xls*', nil, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

Comment: `ShellExecute` is deprecated in favour of `ShellExecuteEx`, the latter being capable of reporting errors in a sane manner. However, since you are executing a new process you would be better to call `CreateProcess`.

Comment: You might want to skip calling another process and use a zip library instead, like the built-in TZipFile, Abbrevia, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text arguments of `ShellExecute` are of type `PChar`. But you supply a string for argument number 4.

The error message is very clear. You know by inspecting the declaration of `ShellExecute` that the problematic argument is of type `PChar` (an alias to `PWideChar`). And the error message tells you that you are passing a `string`.

Instead of

```
'a -r -ta'+ PChar(sdate) +' D:\xlsFiles.rar D:\*.xls*'
```

pass

```
PChar('a -r -ta'+ sdate +' D:\xlsFiles.rar D:\*.xls*')
```

Comment: Thanks , It's work ,
But what is the deference between PChar and PWideChar ??

because the both works !

Comment: That's covered in the second paragraph where I say that `PChar` is an alias to `PWideChar`. It's also documented (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.PChar) but this particular documentation is utter rubbish.......